# Indy10 Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal, lazarus, indy10

I try to follow to install instruction for Indy10 and Lazarus. After downloading [Indy 10 download](https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10), using the correct password I see only Delphi code, no folder with the name lazarus or freepascal. Has the Lazarus version from Indy10 been removed ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a frequent Lazarus user, but I just read these instructions [here](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/fpc/index.en.html) and [here (from wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org)](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/Indy_with_Lazarus). They don't mention any separate Lazarus folder at all.

When I download the latest nighly build, this is confirmed. In the folder `Lib` you can find all package files, including the dpk (Delphi) and the lpk (Lazarus) package files.

In the source (Lib/System), you find `IdCompilerDefines.inc`, which has a lot of defines for various compilers, amongst which FreePascal. These defines are used in the code to make specific exceptions, when needed, in an otherwise shared code base.

Comment: Yes, Indy is a single codebase project. Its source code supports multiple Pascal compilers, including FreePascal. There is a Lazarus makefile provided.

Answer (score 2):

I use Indy 10 with Lazarus on both Windows and Linux. It works great.

I didn't install it into Lazarus via packages. I just directly uses the relevant units and creates objects at runtime. This gives me a project which is very portable between different Lazarus installations.